# How to fix ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

This is my method:

```
def print_relative_strength_by_ticker(self, tickers): # print relative strength
    tickers_list = tickers.split(" ")
    if len(tickers_list) == 1:
        query = "SELECT ticker, rs FROM companyinfo WHERE ticker = %s"
        params = [tickers_list[0]]  # Wrap the single ticker in a list or a tuple
    else:
        query = "SELECT ticker, rs FROM companyinfo WHERE ticker IN %(tickers_tuple)s" # The key 'tickers' is a string that represents the named parameter in the SQL query (%(tickers)s)
        params = {'tickers_tuple': tuple(tickers_list)} # creates a dictionary with a single key-value pair
    df = self.db.read_sql(query, params=params)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print("Ticker:", row['ticker'], "\tRS:", row['rs'])
```

I updated Spyder but did not make any changes to my code. Now I'm getting an error; I've never had one before, and I'm not sure if it's sqlachemly or not; how can I handle this?

```
s.print_relative_strength_by_ticker('estc')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[27], line 1
    s.print_relative_strength_by_ticker('estc')

  File D:\Stocks/Code\stock_analysis_class.py:111 in print_relative_strength_by_ticker
    df = self.db.read_sql(query, params=params)

  File D:\Stocks/Code\mysql_class.py:33 in read_sql
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=params, index_col=index_col)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:682 in read_sql
    return pandas_sql.read_query(

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1776 in read_query
    result = self.execute(sql, params)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1599 in execute
    return self.con.exec_driver_sql(sql, *args)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1767 in exec_driver_sql
    distilled_parameters = _distill_raw_params(parameters)

  File lib\\sqlalchemy\\cyextension\\util.pyx:38 in sqlalchemy.cyextension.util._distill_raw_params

  File lib\\sqlalchemy\\cyextension\\util.pyx:17 in sqlalchemy.cyextension.util._check_item

ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries
```

Comment: It looks like `params = [tickers_list[0]]` is creating a list with a string element.  The error indicates that string elements aren't allowed in list arguments, only tuple and dictionary elements.  At least, that's how I'm interpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 1 ticker argument, the `param` list argument you passed in is a string instead of tuple or dictionary type as indicated in the error message. Have you tried changing the `query` to use `:ticker` as placeholder and `params` as dictionary type instead. So the code above should be from

```
query = "SELECT ticker, rs FROM companyinfo WHERE ticker = %s"
params = [tickers_list[0]]  # Wrap the single ticker in a list or a tuple
```

to

```
query = "SELECT ticker, rs FROM companyinfo WHERE ticker = :ticker"
params = {"ticker": tickers_list[0]}
```